# Cumulative Decision Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Good day,

I have three columns: Game_Date, Decision, Record

For each row (Game_Date

Comment: why you use like on this condition: Season LIKE '2014-2015' , why not equal...

Comment: you should write expected results or join image, not link to it...

Comment: Doesn't equal or LIKE give the same result ?

Comment: yes the same, but different cost of query

Comment: why you group by Decision but not select this field? Don't group by Decision, then you probably get expected result

Comment: You're right. I forgot to remove it, I had the Decision selected but I removed it and forgot to modify my group by

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window ([analytic Function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm))  to get the total per date/season.

NOW TESTED!:

```
With GAME as
(Select to_date('15-MAR-15','DD-MON-YY') as Game_date, 'W' as decision, '2014-2015' as Season from dual UNION ALL
Select  to_date('19-MAR-15','DD-MON-YY') as Game_date, 'L' as decision, '2014-2015' as Season  from dual UNION ALL
Select  to_date('22-MAR-15','DD-MON-YY') as Game_date, 'L' as decision, '2014-2015' as Season  from dual UNION ALL
Select  to_date('24-MAR-15','DD-MON-YY') as Game_date, 'O' as decision, '2014-2015' as Season  from dual UNION ALL
Select  to_date('28-MAR-15','DD-MON-YY') as Game_date, 'W' as decision, '2014-2015' as Season  from dual UNION ALL
Select  to_date('01-APR-15','DD-MON-YY') as Game_date, 'W' as decision, '2014-2015' as Season  from dual )

--YOU ONLY NEED TO RUN THIS PART!!!    
SELECT Game_date AS "Date", Decision,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Decision = 'W' THEN 1 else 0 END) Over (partition by Season order by game_Date) || '-' || 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Decision = 'L' THEN 1 else 0 END) Over (partition by Season order by game_Date) || '-' || 
   SUM (CASE WHEN Decision = 'O' THEN 1 else 0 END) Over (partition by Season order by game_Date) AS "RECORD"
FROM Game
WHERE Season = '2014-2015' 
  --AND (Team_Visitor_ID = 1 OR Team_Home_ID = 1)

ORDER BY Game_Date desc
```

[image]

Comment: The following error message appears although I am using double quotation marks around the alias 
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Working fine for me.... screen shot shows run and results. they were in the wrong order, but I corrected that.

Comment: xQbert, Thanks that works perfectly but I will need to do that for over a 100 Game Dates. It is going to be quite painful if I need to Select each date.

Comment: You don't have to.  Just run the bottom part of the select.  The top part was mocking up your table data without me creating a table... as I don't have your table.  and be sure to uncomment the team_visitor_ID or you'll get combined results for all teams in that Season.

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Hey, you did most the work.  I just showed you how to use a window function to get you the rest of the way.

Comment: You're far too modest haha.
One more question: What does Over Partition By does exactly ?

Comment: it forces the function (be it Sum, Avg, Row_number(), Rank() or others), to group (Partition) the data by season.  So if you eliminated Season 2014-2015 from your where clause and added it as a column, you'd see all that Team's season records in your "game" table.  It defines "What is summed" and it wouldn't Combine the sums of different seasons! (all without a group by...)   VERY powerful stuff.  You could even partition by a team's ID (though with your OR it could be tricky) and get all teams back at once.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just learnt something new and very useful

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
select TO_CHAR(Game_Date, 'DD MON ''YY') AS "DATE",
SUM(W) Over (order by Game_Date) || '-' ||
SUM(L) Over (order by Game_Date) || '-' || 
SUM(O) Over (order by Game_Date) AS "RECORD"
from (
 SELECT Game_Date,
 SUM (CASE WHEN Decision like 'W' THEN 1 END) as W, 
 SUM (CASE WHEN Decision like 'L' THEN 1 END) as L, 
 SUM (CASE WHEN Decision like 'O' THEN 1 END) as O
 FROM Game
 WHERE Season = '2014-2015' AND (Team_Visitor_ID = 1 OR Team_Home_ID = 1)
 GROUP BY Game_Date)
ORDER BY Game_Date DESC;
```

Comment: It works perfectly Adam if you remove the comma just before FROM Game. thank you very much Adam